# Make Babel recognize HTML template tag

Tags: javascript, templates, babeljs

I am writing a frontend application in JavaScript, when a user visits the homepage of the application, the index.js file is to render the contents in `<template id=“card”></template>` to the webpage using [HTMLTemplateElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

Currently the index.js file contains

```
<template id=“card”>
  <div> <p>getting this to work</p> </div>
</template>
const cardClone = document.querySelector('#card').content.cloneNode(true)

// render to webpage
document.querySelector(‘body’).appendChild(cardCloned)
```

*The Issue*
Babel throws an unexpected syntax error pointing at the template tag

*Expected Solution*
How do I make Babel to recognize template tag as a valid

Comment: You asked this exactly [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531148/make-babel-recognizes-html-template-tag) just for an hour ago. What do you think has changed in the rules within that hour?

Comment: The previous post was closed

Comment: Yes, but why do you think a new exactly same question would be answered? You've asked for more details, provide the details.

Comment: Yes this is the updated version. The original version of the previous post does not contain much detail as this, I edited it after it was closed hoping it would be reopened. But since I sincerely need this help for my team, I decided to make a new post. Thanks

Comment: When I compare these two posts character by character, they're exactly the same, no updates here. It looks like you've HTML tags inside the script tag, that shouldn't be there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change “ to " in the id global attribute of the template tag:

```
<template id="card">
  <div>
    <p>getting this to work</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

And ‘ with ' in the second query selector:

```
const cardCloned = document.querySelector('#card').content.cloneNode(true);

// render to webpage
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(cardCloned);
```

Please note that you are calling the wrong constant in that selector as well, so I've changed the name of the constant to match the one that you're trying to call and now it seems to be working.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3ykw46m/) with the complete code as well.